# Powershell HTML doesn't format

Tags: powershell, parsing, html-parsing

I have a script in which I have the following line:

```
$body += "The file " + $item.Name + " is reaching $MaxSize GB! <br> Current Size: <b>" + $SizeInGb.ToString(".00") + " GB </b> <br />"+ "Path to file: " + $Path + "<br /> <br />"
```

The problem is that my HTML doesn't get rendered/parsed (in Outlook)

My mail still shows as:

```
The file SRV20150818.VHD.ebxwyq is reaching 2 GB! <br> Current Size: <b>36,64 GB </b> <br />Path to file: \\srv641\Software G\update\ex\SRV565456.VHD.wyq<br /> <br />
```

Why is this?

The command I use to send my mail is:

```
Send-MailMessage -To "test@ds.test" -From "tesbetest@test.test" -Subject $subject -Body $body -SmtpServer 192.168.16.18
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `-BodyAsHtml` in Send-MailMessage

```
Send-MailMessage -To "test@ds.test" -From "tesbetest@test.test" -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 192.168.16.18
```